# How do I use d3.nest inside my react-reducer?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I've the following reducer :

```
const initialState = {data1:null, data2:null, isFetching: false,error:null};
export const gaData = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {    
        case 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
        return Object.assign(
            {},state, 
        {data1: action.data1, 
         data2: action.data2.map( ([x, y, z]) => ({ x, y, z }) ), 
         isFetching: action.isFetching,
         error: null });
        default:return state;
    }
};
```

How do I use `d3.nest` so I can nest `x` value and rollup `y` value for `data2` ?

If I'm right I would to do something like this :

```
var newdata = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .rollup(function(d) { return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.y;}); }) 
    .entries(data2);
```

but I don't know do to include this in my reducer.

Comment: It's not clear how you want to use `newdata` in your reducer. Why can't you just assign the result to the relevant part of your new state object?

Comment: Hi Tom, what do you mean when you say _Why can't you just assign the result to the relevant part of your new state object?_ I don't understand you.

Comment: I mean that I don't know how you want to use `newdata` in the reducer. Where should it go? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: hum... I'm a beginner so I think It's really a beginner issue. I would like to do something like this `data2: action.data2.map( ([x, y, z]) => ({ x, y, z }) ).nest() .key(function(d) { return d.x; }).rollup(function(d) { return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.y;}); }).entries(data2)` but since `d3.nest` only work with a variable, I don't know how to use it in my reducer... it's it clearer ?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add detail, rather than using the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you just want to do something like this:

```
    case 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
        let data2 = action.data2.map(([x, y, z]) => ({ x, y, z }));
        data2 = d3.nest()
            .key(function (d) { return d.x; })
            .rollup(function (d) { return d3.sum(d, function (g) { return g.y; }); })
            .entries(data2);
```

Then you can just return `data2` as part of the new state object.

As an aside, consider changing your variable name to something more meaningful than `data2`!